# where do I find firebase documentation for react native

Tags: firebase, react-native

I have installed `firebase` module for react native app

```
npm install firebase --save
```

what I'm looking for is the documentation for this module , I had searched many times but did't find any thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Firebase node.js client SDK is mostly a variant of the regular Firebase JavaScript client. You can find its documentation here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup. There is no specific documentation for React Native, although there is a blog post here: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/07/firebase-react-native.html

Answer (score 1):

Firebase has not released any specific api for react-native. So you have to go with Web api of firebase to build apps in react-native.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/

Answer (score 0):

Firebase has not released any specific api for react-native. So you have to go with Web api of firebase to build apps in react-native.